# Cadence SoC encounter

Tags: simulation, layout, synthesis, asic, cadence

I am trying to create the layout of my design for an 8 bit multiplier accumulator in SoC Cadence encounter tool. After routing the design using `wroute` command, the tool is generating many shorting and overlapping errors. How can I solve these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way of minimizing the shorting and overlapping errors is to the increase the chip area during Floor planning. This can be done by increasing the dimensions of the chip. Increasing the area also reduces the time taken by `wRoute` for routing small designs.

Answer (score 0):

**Steps to follow to debug DRC violations**

*Primary checks* :

1. Check which layer the violations are mostly in
2. Rerun the wroute step specifying higher number of end iteration

*To confirm it is not a tool bug* :

1. Select the violation in the Violation Browser and check the violation description
2. Compare the measurements in the description to the LEF